# Iterate through JSON object using DOJO or javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I have my json object coming from ajax resaponse.It looks like this.

```
{    
  "customerID": "87545",    
  "parentCustomerID": "Parent:87545",   
  "relationshipID": "87545-- Rel 1234",    
  "customerName": "87545-- John Snow",    
  "constitution": "87545-- consti" 
}
```

Now I want to iterate through this either using DOJO 1.10 library or normal for loop javascript.But I am not able to get the loop through. I have tried the approach for

```
require(["dojo/_base/array"], 
function(array){
    array.forEach(JSON.stringify(ajaxJsonData), function(entry, i){ });       
});
```

Can anyont please help me ?

NB: this json object is coming dynamically each time and the keys are the same as the id  of the input types in my jsp page. So i need to get the key and the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in Javascript:

```
var obj = { "customerID": "87545", "parentCustomerID": "Parent:87545",
"relationshipID": "87545-- Rel 1234", "customerName": "87545-- John Snow", "constitution": "87545-- consti" };

for (var key in obj) {

   console.log(key +":" +obj[key]);

}
```

Explanation: It will iterate over all the keys present in `obj` and print it along with the corresponding value in the `obj` using `obj[key]`.

You can check the results by copying the above code in your browser's console.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this and wanted to point out that you could end up iterating over something you don't want.  Consider adding a check inside your loop:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key, obj[key]);
    }
}
```

This keeps you from accidentally working with something up the prototype chain on accident.  I prefer using `Object.keys` which does the same check and more:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

TLDR; Run this and ask yourself if it's what you want:

```js
function Person() {
 this.name = 'Joe';
 this.age = 21;
}
Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
 console.log('Hi my name is ' + this.name + ', I am ' + this.age);
};

var obj = new Person();
obj.sayHello();
for (var key in obj) {
 console.log(key, obj[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this using javascript

```
for(var key in  yourObj) {
    var value = yourObj[key];
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a js fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/qo0669dx/1/

```
var Obj = {
    "customerID": "87545",
    "parentCustomerID": "Parent:87545",
    "relationshipID": "87545-- Rel 1234", 
    "customerName": "87545-- John Snow", 
    "constitution": "87545-- consti" 
}

for (var key in Obj) {
    console.log(key + ":" + Obj[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is Object not Array. To iterate through object you can use `for in`

```js
var obj = { "customerID": "87545", "parentCustomerID": "Parent:87545",
"relationshipID": "87545-- Rel 1234", "customerName": "87545-- John Snow", "constitution": "87545-- consti" }

for(var prop in obj) {
   console.log(obj[prop]);
}
```